# Adding a sound when an user aproach a marker on GoogleMaps API V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I developed an application using GoogleMaps with the new API 2.0, the app is working and everything and basically it showns the user's location and some markers, those delimits the off limits area in some cities here in italy. I would like to add a sound when the user aproach one maker, but seems there are no method to interact with the objects added on the map. My idea, a really bad idea, is to work with user's coordinates and a matrix of markers coordinates, then checking where the user is near to; slow and bad I can see it.

So my question is:

Is there a common way to check when the user is near a POI and add a sound to this listener ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my answer help you. :)

Use LocationManager and LocationListener. You can get the user's gps postion in real-time. OS push the "Location" to the "onLocationChanged()" that you should implement for LocationListener. Check the distance between Location of listener and your Marker's Lat/Lon.
Play the sound when user approach in 500m (maybe..)

FYI, you can request GPS and NETWORK lcoation simultaneously.
you may know Network position is not accurate. Use GPS position if you need more precise user's position.

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0f, mLocationListenerGPS);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0f, mLocationListenerNetwork);
```

And do not forget removing requesting if you don't need locating.

```
mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListenerGPS);
mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListenerNetwork);
```

Do not use locating for a long time. Locating uses huge battery.

Comment: That's what I thought too, as I wrote in the question. But I hoped to find a more "professional" way to do that. Thanks in any case, I'll mark your as answer also if it's not a solution for me, because other people could find it useful.

Thanks anyway =)

Comment: @Anearion Thank you for accepting my answer although my answer is not suitable. Anyway, Did you read this script on google developer's page? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html I learned lots of thing from this script. :)